# $firebase promise resolve in phonegap app

Tags: firebase, angularfire

i am stuck with this for few days now.

I have route with resolve, which looks something like this:

```
.when('/list/',{
   controller : 'list',
      templateUrl : 'template/list.stache',
      resolve : {
        list : function($q,$firebase){
          var d = $q.defer(),
              ref = new Firebase(_config.url+'/list/');

         ref.once('value', function(s){
            if(s.val() == null){
              d.reject('Object not found');
            }

            d.resolve($firebase(ref));
         });

            return d.promise;
        }
   }

})
```

It works great in any browser, for some reason it fails in Android app ( using phonegap ), it loads data correctly, but when you try to save it ( using $save() ), data updates locally but fails to do so remotely.

Tested few theories, tried to call $firebase within controller, using something like:

```
    $scope.fb = $firebase(new Firebase(_config.url+'/list/'))
    $scope.fb.$on('loaded', function(d){
        $scope.fb[$scope.fb.$getIndex()[0]].test = 'AAAAAA!'
        $scope.fb.$save()

    })
```

The above worked as should, so i assume it has something to do with promises.

Would anyone have any ideas?

EDIT ---

Still struggling to figure out the issue, but was able to narrow it down to resolve:

```
.when('/list/',{
  controller : function(){
     new Firebase('https://XXX.firebaseio.com/test/').push('Hey!');
  },
  templateUrl : 'template/list.stache',
  resolve : {
    list : function($q,$firebase){
      var d = $q.defer(),
          ref = new Firebase(_config.url+'/list/');

     ref.once('value', function(s){
        if(s.val() == null){
          d.reject('Object not found');
        }

        d.resolve($firebase(ref));
     });

        return d.promise;
    }
 }

})
```

It fails. But :

```
.when('/list/',{
  controller : function(){
     new Firebase('https://XXX.firebaseio.com/test/').push('Hey!');
  },
  templateUrl : 'template/list.stache'
})
```

Works as expected.

Note that both approaches works fine in a browser ( tested on firefox and chrome ). It only fails when compiled to android app using phonegap.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: How do it fail on Android? Precision here will be helpful in understanding the error and use case. If it's not sending data remotely, there will be an error somewhere we can inspect.

Comment: That's the problem, that it doesn't give any error, I had to fall back to calling fb in controller, which is a bit inconvenient from the ux. The main problem that the returned object (from resolve) has all methods ($save() etc ) but whenever you try to call anyof them, you can see changes on local data, but not remote

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/267

Answer (score -1):

I had the same thing. The connection is lost.

Use the function `Firebase.goOffline();` and `Firebase.goOnline();`. This allows you to manually control the client connection.

Example:

```
var usersRef = new Firebase('https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users');
Firebase.goOffline(); // All Firebase instances are disconnected
Firebase.goOnline(); // All Firebase instances automatically reconnect
```

[Link for reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/goonline.html)